# php error Function name must be a string php

Tags: php, dynamic, include, directory

I'm building a dynamic website, but the pages are not showing up because of the error

*Fatal error: Function name must be a string php*

on the line

```
 $p= $_GET('p');
```

The whole code for including the files is

```
 $folder = 'de/';
 $folder =  'en/';
 if(!empty($_GET['p'])){

 $pages = scandir($folder,0);
 unset($pages[0],$pages[1]);
 $p= $_GET('p');
 if(in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)){
 include($folder.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');

 }else{
 echo 'error message';
 }
 }else{
  include($folder.'home.inc.php');    
 }
```

What's wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**

I've updated the code, but now i get the error

```
*failed to open stream: No such file or directory*
```

I'm working on a local server.

Comment: You should check if `p` exist in the `$_GET` array first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite inefficient. Why slurp up the directory's contents into an array and then search the array when you could simply have:

```
if (isset($_GET['p']) {
    $file = $folder . $_GET['p'] .'.inc.php';
    if (is_readable($file)) {
       include($file);
    } else {
       die('error');
    }
} else {
    include($folder.'home.inc.php');    
}
```

This is BY FAR simpler than your convoluted logic. It is however, also vulnerable to the exact same vulnerability: you're allow the user to specify a full path to ANY `*.inc.php` file on your server for which they know the path name. Depending on your setup, this could allow the user to include files which you ever intended to be executed in this manner and leak internal details of your system/configuration.

Comment: I thought i would be ok with an .htaccess file. But your code is for sure better. Anyway, now i get an error that the directories are not existing. Look at my update please.

Comment: .htaccess can't protect you, unless you list every single VALID file you'd like to allow to be included.

Comment: with your code i got an syntax error for the `{` bracket on the first line. The last `[` on the same line should be `]` which i correct it in my attempt with your code. But the `{` on the first line seems to be correct.

Comment: yeah. that `[` was a typo. fixed now.

Comment: There was another typo for the closing `if()` on the first line. Apart from that, how to include the two folders en + de to make your code working?

Comment: you'd need two include calls, then. your version doesn't include two folders either. `$folder = 'en'; $folder = 'de'` doesn't add de to en, it just REPLACES en with de and you end up with just `de`.

Answer (score 6):

```
$p= $_GET('p');
```

should be

```
$p= $_GET['p'];
```

Comment: now i get the error _failed to open stream: No such file or directory_ , but why? the directories are existing?

Comment: Why do you define `$folder` twice?

Comment: Because there are two folders; each for one language.

Comment: Your second $folder overwrites the first one.

Comment: But how to write the code in a correct way to include two folders in my website? I thning using the array ist correct :-(

Comment: What do you mean two folders? What's the path?

Comment: One folder is for the german files (de) and another for the english files (en).

Comment: How is the script supposed to know which path to use unless you tell it?

Comment: I thought an array would be ok; i'm still learning and don't know how to write it in a correct way to include two folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
$p= $_GET('p');
```

You really didn't notice that you were using parenthesis?

Use:

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$p= $_GET('p');` it should be `$p= $_GET['p'];`

Answer (score 0):

The error seems $_GET('p') should be $_GET['p'] instead.

A few considerations:

The if(!empty($_GET['p'])), could be changed to if (array_key_exists('p', $_GET) && !empty($_GET['p']) instead.  PHP always complain about array indexes and it's a good way to prevent it.

on unset($pages[0],$pages[1]);, if the array doesn't return 2 elements, it will return null and PHP unset function will complain.  A better way could you check if there are elements on $pages variable;

In case of scandir doesn't return any element, not sure if it'll return null or array, so in this case if(in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)) will throw a error.

Cheers